# "shorthand" - uncountable or not?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

Cambridge dictionary lists "shorthand" as an uncountable word.

(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shorthand)

However, I see a lot of its usage with the indefinite article. For example:

> - Another was labeled "Braves," a shorthand for ICE. - The New York Times
> - Developers have a shorthand for this style: the "classic graybox". - The New Yorker
> - There's a shorthand for this type of guy. - The Guardian - Film
> - "Bach and Beethoven" has become a shorthand for Western classical music. - Britannica

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary definition that you cite is the traditional meaning. It is a skill that is rapidly being lost because voice recognition technology can replace it. The name of a skill is uncountable.

The usage that you are referring to is relatively new one that takes advantage of an existing word to mean something new but related. That meaning is a word or phrase routinely used as an allusive name for something. “Name” is a countable noun.

One meaning is countable; the other is not.